# Transform string into image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Another jQuery question for you guys.

Say I have a url of an image in my web page surrounded by square brackets.

```
[http://www.example.com/picture.jpg]
```

How could I, with jQuery transform that string like so...

```
[http://www.example.com/picture.jpg]
```

into...

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/picture.jpg" />
```

?

Comment: That depends on what you call an image. How do you know whether http://www.example.com/foo.php is an image? Do you care? Can you be certain everything in square brackets is an image path?

Comment: also, what do you start out with? the specific strings with the square brackets or do you want to convert any text on the page surrounded by square brackets into images?

Comment: @Dominic This is a very niche project and there won't be any other urls inside these brackets. 

@cobbal Basically, grab the url inside the brackets and append into the src of the img attribute.

Comment: can't you use [img][/img] instead of just square brackets?

Comment: @Natrium, not the point, but yes I could, as mentioned this is a very niche project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this

```
$("some-selector").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\[(http:.*?)\]/gi, function(str, p1){
        return "<img src='"+p1+"' />";
    }));
});
```

"some-selector" should try to pinpoint where these string occur. If there is nothing like it... just put "body" and see what happens :)

Comment: Thank you but no joy I'm afriad

Comment: There was a mistake in it... I have to use $(this). Maybe it works now :)

Comment: So so close, thank you! - I get: <img src="[http://www.example.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/virgin_media.jpg"/> - Just need to get rid of the left bracket?

Comment: Ah! This guy know Regex X( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077541/regular-expression-joke-explanation